# How to create a nonEmpty list?

Tags: haskell

I want to use [Data.List.NonEmpty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html), I'm searching how to define a list with one element ? I can only fine nonEmpty with a list, but obviously it returns a Maybe and I don't want that...

Update : I find this solution

```
let emptyList = 5 :| []
```

Comment: `type NonEmptyList a = (a, [a])` is an ugly but suitable definition.

Comment: There's an applicative instance so `pure 5`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [OverloadedLists](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overloaded-lists) extension the usual list syntax can be used to define any [IsList](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#the-islist-class) entity (such as [NonEmpty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18/docs/src/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#line-195)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}

import Data.List.NonEmpty

l :: NonEmpty Int
l = [42]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I think it defeat the purpose of `NonEmpty`, since `[] :: NonEmpty Int` would pass compilation but fail at runtime.

Comment: @Jean-BaptistePotonnier Correct. Sadly it looks like a source plugin might be needed: https://github.com/chshersh/ghc-plugin-non-empty

Answer (score 6):

`fromList` takes any non-empty list value.

```
> fromList [5]
5 :| []
```

If you want a function of type `a -> NonEmpty a`, then

```
singleton = fromList . (:[])
```

(I'm surprised `singleton` isn't already in the package.)

(Or as @Lee mentioned in the comments, `singleton = pure` using
the `Applicative` instance for `NonEmpty`.)

Your solution of `5 :| []` is also fine, as `:|` is *the* way to create a new `NonEmpty` value; the functions are just wrappers around its use. (In fact, `pure` is *defined* as `pure a = a :| []`, and `fromList (a:as) = a :| as`.)